# xPath - scraping data from nested div in external site

Tags: php, html, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to scrape variants from a website I used xPath

```
<?php

$html = <<<HTML
<div class="variants"><div class="selected sp-itm" title="Beden seçmek için tıklayınız">36</div><div class="sp-itm" title="Beden seçmek için tıklayınız">37</div><div class="so sp-itm" title="Beden seçmek için tıklayınız">38<span class="i-alarm"></span></div><div class="sp-itm" title="Beden seçmek için tıklayınız">39</div><div class="sp-itm" title="Beden seçmek için tıklayınız">40</div></div>
HTML;

$doc = new \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="variants"]//div[@class="selected sp-itm" or @class="sp-itm"]') as $pWithinDiv) { 
  echo $pWithinDiv->textContent, PHP_EOL;
}
```

And the result is

```
36
37
39
40
```

That's what I need the available sizes in the link but when I'm trying to get these data from the link no a static html tags

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    $url = 'https://www.trendyol.com/lacoste/ziane-plus-grand-kadin-siyah-sneaker-p-83745192';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '');
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $doc = new \DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($data);
    
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);

        foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="variants"]//div[@class="selected sp-itm" or @class="sp-itm"]') as $pWithinDiv) { 
          echo $pWithinDiv->textContent, PHP_EOL;
        }
?>
```

The result is only 36 other opetion not showing with the same query I need to know what is wrong in my code when I add a link!

Comment: If you view `$data` is the content the same?

Comment: the content is the same but they don't return all in the divs @user3783243

Comment: By "they don't return all in the divs " are you repeating the problem statement or do you mean not all the divs are present after curling?

Comment: Yes! I mean not all the divs are present after curling, it's the size of product if you checked the link @user3783243

Comment: So that's the issue. There is only 1 product, not all the products. I don't follow links/URLs. You'll need to see what is different between URL you have and URL you used to get the HTML, possibly AJAX populating the DOM.